# How to write a mathematical formula in English?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-request

Consider:

We define a parameter ***N*** which stands for the number of antennas used in a cell phone network.

After doing a research work, studies show that another parameter of the system which represents diversity order of the network, denoted by ***D***,can be derived as below:

> D = N+1.

The researcher writes about his conclusion as:

> The diversity order of the cell phone network is limited to **one plus the number of antennas**.

Has the researcher written his conclusion correctly? Is it a proper written English?

If no, can you help him to improve his paper?!

---

Adding information due to the incisive comment from ***probablyme***

He asked:

"Is N+1 a bound?"

The answer is **yes**, it expresses the upper band of the diversity order.

Comment: What is the unit on "performance"?

Comment: Is quality measured in terms of "performance"? Is N+1 really a lower, upper, or other kind of limit of performance?

Comment: No actually, I assume that the units are appropriate. I just need to know if performance represents quality. Also, is N+1 a bound? If it is, then the word _limited_ is ok. If N+1 is not a bound, then you cannot say that that the performance is "limited to".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saying "limited to" suggest the diversity order can be anything less than the number of antennas up to and including `A`. If that is what you mean, then "limited" is okay. If it can only be exactly `A`, then you should use "equal to." Yes, that's what the equation says, but it's not necessary to be florid in this instance.

If the diversity order is exactly equal to `A + 1`, the only thing I would say is that it's stylistically better, better to say "plus one" after "antennas," because the number of antennas seems to be the real point, not the fact that they're added to one.

> ... **equal** to the **number of antennas plus one.**

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understand why you want me to delete it?

Comment: To clarify, before I edit, if someone asked you "What is the performance indicator for this network?" and the network had seven antennas, you would tell him "Eight."?

Comment: Okay, so if you had a network with ten antennas, the diversity order could be anything from 0 to 11?

Comment: Okay, thanks. In that case, I don't think it would be considered a "bound," though.

Comment: Now, can I say sth limits the D to N+1 ?

Comment: Well, what is "sth"?

Comment: abbreviated version of something ! :)

Comment: Well, I'm hesitant to say for sure, since I'm not an expert, but that seems well-constructed to me. Maybe avoid "limits" since it has mathematical connotations? That's probably best asked as another question

Comment: It is not very important. The key part was the **sth plus sth else***. Many Thanks for your contributions bro